# How to get previous version using git and VS Express for web 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I want to find the cause of a bug which caused by one of the recent commits. Is it possible to get a specific version, and then undo the checkouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a specific version via `git checkout [commit_id]`. You can undo that commit with `git revert [commit_id]`.

Comment: Is it possible from the VS UI?

Comment: Looks like you can revert a commit in the VS UI, but not check one out! If you want a better UI for Git, I can suggest two: SourceTree (https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and Tortoise Git (https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

Comment: Thanks, I used the command prompt tools for git and vs and managed to get the specific version using your answer.